# Ошибка на heroku при использовании webdriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, heroku

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь разместить на heroku этот кусок кода

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from lxml.html import fromstring
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def scrap_url(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    options.binary_location = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    # get chromedriver from 
    # https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver')
    browser.get(url)
    html_doc = browser.page_source
    tree = fromstring(html_doc)
    links = ['http://1xstavka.ru/ru/%s' % link.get('href') for link in tree.xpath('//a[@class="c-events__name"]')]
    # print(links)
    browser.close()
    return html_doc

os.environ["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"

urls = ['https://google.com',
        'https://google.com',
        ]


start_time = time.time()

pool = Pool(cpu_count())
pool.map(scrap_url, urls)
pool.close()

print(time.time() - start_time)
```

На моей машине работает нормально, а вот на хероку ругается:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/verify_games.py", line 35, in <module>
    pool.map(scrap_url, urls)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py .   ", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 
  (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1014-aws x86_64)
```

С одним url работает нормально, а вот когда несколько - такая ошибка
Заранее спасибо.